# How to make Play Store like ToolBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to make a toolbar that behaves like the toolbar of PlayStore app.

I am not interested in the "search" feature. I am interested in the transparency which reveals the layout behind it. And after scrolling up the background becomes solid.

This is the first state displaying transparent background revealing the layout underneath it.

[image: transparent_background_revealing_layout_underneath]

This is the toolbar with solid background displaying the title.

[image: solid_background_hiding_layout]

I am not interested in the third state where the complete toolbar is completely hidden.

[image: toolbar_completely_hidden]

Although it won't harm to have this in my app; but my primary goal is to get the first two effects.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Android's Material Design. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html).